# Best method for importing data from text file into MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, performance, sqlbulkcopy

In need of your opinions. Currently developing an application in VB.NET.

I have a text file which contains more than one thousand rows. Each rows contains the data needed to be inserted into the database. A sample of a row is as follows:

```
0001--------SCOMNET--------0.100---0.105
```

At first glance, one might figured that each column was separated with a tab but actually each column was separated by blank spaces (I used '-' to denote as blank spaces because somehow could not get SO text editor to show the blank spaces).

The first column is defined by

```
Substring(0, 12) which is the data [0001--------]
```

second column

```
Substring(12, 12) in which the data is [SCOMNET-----]
```

third column is

```
Substring(24, 8) in which the data is [---0.100]
```

and last column is

```
Substring(32, 8) in which the data is [---0.105]
```

My initial though is to extract the lines for the text file and stored in as a list of strings, then while looping, do the separation of the each string item in the list with the SubString() function and insert it one by one until the end of the list. But this will no doubt takes time.

In my scenario, how can I take advantage of the SqlBulkCopy? Or if there is any other ways to approach this for a faster insert? Say;

- open file
- start loop

  - read line
  - separate each column in the line with substring
  - save in a DataTable
- end loop
- BCP(DataTable)

Comment: If the file is formatted I would suggest Bulk Insert http://code217.blogspot.com/2014/11/load-large-text-file-to-sql-server.html

Comment: for faster save in DataBase use Entity Framework ;)

Comment: Or follow  @inquisitive_mind link .. you will find a very good example !

Answer (score 1):

This includes a method that may be a more efficient way of reading your text file.

```
    Sub readFixWidthTextFileIntoSqlTable()

    Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection("Connection String Goes Here")
    sqlConn.Open()
    Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand
    sqlComm.Connection = sqlConn
    sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    sqlComm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO YourTableNameHere VALUES(@Field1, @Field2, @Field3, @Field4)"

    sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@Field1", SqlDbType.Text)
    sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@Field2", SqlDbType.Text)
    sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@Field3", SqlDbType.Text)
    sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@Field4", SqlDbType.Text)



    Using IFReader As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(FileNameWithPath)
        IFReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.FixedWidth
        IFReader.SetFieldWidths(12, 12, 8, 8)

        While Not IFReader.EndOfData
            Dim fields As String() = IFReader.ReadFields

            sqlComm.Parameters("@Field1").Value = fields(0)
            sqlComm.Parameters("@Field2").Value = fields(1)
            sqlComm.Parameters("@Field3").Value = fields(2)
            sqlComm.Parameters("@Field4").Value = fields(3)
            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End While

    End Using

    sqlConn.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got it pretty much right. This approach is one that I take a lot. Here's a bit of sample code to get you started. It is ONLY an example, there's absolutely no validation or and no consideration for Primary Keys on the table. If you want to review your question with more details of the structure of the destination table then I can make this example much more specific.

```
 Read_File:

    Dim sFileContents As String = ""

    Using sRead As New StreamReader("e:\ExampleFile.txt")
        sFileContents = sRead.ReadToEnd
    End Using

    Dim sFileLines() As String = sFileContents.Split(vbCrLf)

Connect_To_DB:

    Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection

    sqlConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=YourServerName;Initial Catalog=YourDbName;Integrated Security=True"
    sqlConn.Open()

Setup_DataTable:

    Dim ExampleTable As New DataTable
    ExampleTable.Load(New SqlCommand("Select Top 0 * From Example_Table", sqlConn).ExecuteReader)
    'This is not absolutely necessary but avoids trouble with NOT NULL columns (like keys)'
    For Each dcColumn As DataColumn In ExampleTable.Columns : dcColumn.AllowDBNull = True : Next dcColumn

Save_To_DataTable:

    For Each sLine In sFileLines

        Dim ExampleRow As DataRow = ExampleTable.NewRow

        ExampleRow("First_Column_Name") = sLine.Substring(0, 12).TrimEnd
        ExampleRow("Second_Column_Name") = sLine.Substring(12, 12).TrimEnd
        ExampleRow("Third_Column_Name") = sLine.Substring(24, 8).TrimEnd
        ExampleRow("Fourth_Column_Name") = sLine.Substring(32, 8).TrimEnd

        ExampleTable.Rows.Add(ExampleRow)

    Next

Update_Database:

    If ExampleTable.Rows.Count <> 0 Then

        Dim sqlBulk As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(sqlMvConnection)

        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Example_Table"
        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(ExampleTable)

    End If

Disconnect_From_DB:

    sqlConn.Close()
```

Also, as commented on above and if you have access to it SSIS will do this in a jiffy.