# Import delimited text files to SQL table with fixed columns with VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, text, import

Hi I need some help in understanding what is the best way to go about this problem I have. I have these text files that are placed in a folder throughout the day so there can me multiple files in the folder, and each file has thousands of rows. I need to import these comma delimited text files to a table in my sql database.

There are supposed to be 9 columns separated by a comma, sometimes the client sends bad data like files such as: "1245,5656,HG,," when its supposed to be "1244,9000,ET,TI,09,V3,,,6.9". I need to do this via VB.net since the other parts of the overall process are in vb.net so I need to modify the code to incorporate the import part.

So my idea is to create a datable with premade columns then import the data to the datatable and somehow catch the bad files and send them to another folder. Is there a way to loop through the folder, import the delimited files to a datatable to confirm the right amount of columns are used and then import them to a DB datatabase table and move the bad data files elsewhere?

I am searching on this site ways to do this as I have never imported text files to sqll via vb.net before but I found another question and I was wondering if that first answer is in the right direction? The question I am referring to:[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166641/best-method-for-importing-data-from-text-file-into-ms-sql-server)

Comment: Read the file in line by line, split the line on the delimiter, count the number of elements in the array, if correct then place the array elements into a datatable object. After all lines are done, merge the datatable object into the SQL database with a tableadapter.

Comment: You may want to use SSIS package for this, if it is possible - it would very easy and solid solution.

Comment: @AlekseyRatnikov Thank you for the suggestion but I have to use VB.net for this task unfortunately.

Comment: VB.NET has a `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` but I've not used it enough to know if it helps here.